# Running and Importing files folder along with runnable jar in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line, jar

I have a project in eclipse where all my source code is under mbl/src. I am exporting this code as a runnable jar. I have got another folder under mbl/files which contains some of the properties files.I want to export these files also but eclipse doesnt give any such option. I have put the mbl/files under add class folder in build path options  but still I am facing similar issues. I have also put the files folder directly under src folder but still it is not able to access it.I am using following options in commandline.

java -jar myprogram.jar arg1

It gives this error:

*Unable to find files/text1.properties*

text1.properties is under mbl/files/text1.properties

and is referred in the following manner from main class:

```
FileInputStream fs=new FileInputStream("files\\text1.properties");
```

Answer (score 0):

Resources in bedded within Jars, need to be read via the `Class.getResource(...)` method.

This method returns an `URL` object, from which you can obtain an `InputStream`